# Struts: HTML Option Selected?

Tags: html, html-select, struts

In struts, it seems there is no "selected" option. The HTML option tag has a selected attribute such that you can do:

```
<option selected="selected">Some Option</option>
```

and that option will be automatically selected. Is there a way to do this in struts? It seems that in struts, its randomly auto-selected one my options for a reason I don't understand and I would like to be able to specify which option should be auto selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Struts this is done in the `<html:select>` tag and not in the `<html:option>` like for the the case of plain HTML `option`.

The `value` attribute of the [`<html:select>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#select) tag is used to compare against each `<html:option>` value and marking it as selected if a match is found.