# How to auto select drop down box value in struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am loading java list values in my drop down box.Now i just want to auto select one value from the list by default.we may introduce logic for this either in java side or jsp side.

**Here is my JSP part..**

```
<label class="labelStyles" for="planAction">Plan Action:</label>
<html:select styleId="planAction" name="PAMaintenanceProblemProgramForm" 
             property="planAction">
      <html:options collection="validPlanAction" property="code" labelProperty="desc"/>
</html:select>
```

**Java Code is**

```
session.setAttribute("validPlanAction",delegate.getPlanActionList());
```

How do i make this as auto select by default?

Comment: You meant select one value by default? If so, then you can use selected="selected". Look here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262190/struts-html-option-selected

Comment: yes.But the value coming as a LIST.I want to make the fist item in the list as selected by default..There is no static options available. How do i pick the first item in the list in <html:select> value attribute..?